# How to add proxy configuration in web.config file and remove from appsettings.json in .NET 6 with Angular 5?

Tags: angular5, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, hot-module-replacement, webpack-dev-middleware

How to Add proxy configuration inside web.config file by removeing proxy from appsettings.json file in .net6 with Angular 5?

I tried to add proxy in web.config file by removing from appsetting.json file.
Code added in web config file is as below :

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\foo.f00.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\log..\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
  <environmentVariables>
  <environmentVariable name="http_proxy" value=http://myproxy.abc.com:8080/>
  <environmentVariable name="https_proxy" value=https://myproxy.abc.com:8080/>
  <environmentVariable name="no_proxy" value=".local,.www.com"/>
</environmentVariables>
```

If i write only **https and no_proxy** then application runs **without** any exception.
**But**
When I write **http** proxy and run application then it **throws exception** on code as below:-

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
  HotModuleReplacement = true
});
```

And Error as below:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. 
(Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', 
line 0, position 0.)'
```

geetting in startup.cs file on UseWebpackDevMiddleware

**Now Expectation is that**, How to remove above error? And Is  WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions, HotModuleReplacement is supports http value in .net6 with angular5?

Comment: i guess you missing " in value="http://www.com:8080"

Comment: The above value is for example only actually my value is like: 
    <environmentVariable name="http_proxy" value="http://abc.pqr.com:8080"/> and only  because of this value i.e (http://..) webpackdevmiddlewareoptions
{
HotModuleReplacement=true
} 
is throwing exception.
If I pass only Https (Secured) value including no_proxy then Not getting any Exception.